# $.each is iterating through each character in array

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, loops, each

I'm creating an array by pulling data from a json ajax request. But using that array in another `$.each` statement is resulting in iteration over each character rather than each value.

```
var setInfo = [];

$.ajax({ 
  url: blah,
  async: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function{
    $.each(data.photosets.photoset, function(i,photoinfo) {
            setInfo.push(photoinfo.id);
    }) // completed set values look like 1234,5678,etc..
  holler();
})

function holler() {
$.each(setInfo, function(index, value) {
    // using each array value in here splits into each 
    // character rather than each value. So rather than 
    // iterating through each whole value 1234,5678,etc.. 
    // It is iterating as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,and so on.
    var url1 = "http://www.test.com/" + value;
    // Rather than http://www.test.com/1234, value is being evaluated as just 1
    // so the result is http://www.test.com/1
 });
```

Here's a sample of the json response in which I am getting the id:

```
    ({"photosets":{"photoset":
[{"id":"123456789", "primary":"102932423", "secret":"19ca84349a", "server":"5143", "farm":6, "photos":"52", "videos":0, "title":{"_content":"Thanksgiving 2010"}, "description":{"_content":""}}, 
{"id":"012345678", "primary":"1294872352", "secret":"983a9c58d1", "server":"5184", "farm":6, "photos":"12", "videos":0, "title":{"_content":"24th Birthday Dinner at McCormick and Schmitts"}, "description":{"_content":""}}]}, "stat":"ok"})
```

Edit:

It appears that I has a piece of code which I'm assuming was turning the array into a string:

```
 setInfo += '';
```

running my code in console on firebug while on stackoverflow, I'm able to see that an array is now showing up as [1234,5678] BUT running locally, I'm getting a weird jQuery error:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 5579"  data: no]

Line 0
```

Comment: [Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating that jQuery does not do what you say it does.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/U7UWB/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code and it works as expected with the data you provided. I would suggest to use console.log inside your function to see what's happening in your arrays.

```
> x=    ({"photosets":{"photo set":[{"id":"123456789", "primary":"102932423",...
> xx=[]
> $.each(x.photosets.photoset,function(i,photoinfo){ xx.push(photoinfo.id); });
> xx
["123456789", "012345678"]
> $.each(xx,function(index,value){ console.log(value); });
123456789
012345678
```

Comment: Just attempted that, it appears that each character is being split out

Comment: It definitely does not do that.

Comment: i guess that setInfo += '' was at fault then?

Comment: @romanish I though so .. but I'm now getting an error (pasted above). When using the firebug console while on stackoverflow, I'm getting a good array but when loading the actual page locally, I'm getting the jQuery error above. I've attempted to switch to stackoverflow's same version of jQuery, but no luck.

Comment: @romanish, your reminder of throwing console.log() in the mix helped me debug and ultimately figure out my error. I had initially wanted to run this script and throw the resulting array into my html file for another ajax call to use for reference. My error was including this: $('#flickrSets').html(setInfo); removing that line fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went through same problem. My JSON response from servlet was simple array:
    ["one", "two"] 
While iterating using jquery ajax, it was going through each character and not elements as a whole, even though at servlet end, response content type was set to "application/json". Then I added dataType: 'json' in ajax call properties, it worked.

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data: {
        moduleName: moduleName,
        action: 'getSubModules'
    },
    dataType: 'json', //this one
    url:'AjaxController',
    success: function(response){
        $.each(response, function(index, value) {
            alert('value');
        });
    }
});
```

I think it was considering the response as plain string earlier.